# How to use hooks in workspaces with husky in root package.json?

Tags: package.json, githooks, linter, husky, git-husky

I have to run a command which validates schema during pre-commit using husky hooks.

Husky is included in package.json of root directory like this:

```
"workspaces": {
        "packages": [
            "apps",
            "vendors/*"
        ],
        "nohoist": [
            "**/husky",
            "**/husky/**"
        ]
}
```

In sub-directories it is defined as this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^1.3.1"
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "commit-msg": "yarn commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
        "pre-commit": "yarn lint",
        "post-merge": "git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD | grep --quiet config.json && cd .. && yarn compose"
    }
},
```

How can I define a hook in the root directory like it is defined in the sub-directory ?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a better question for Husky's GitHub.